# If timestamp falls between other 2 timestamp of same person for another booking

Tags: sql, timestamp

I have a table below.

[booking_person TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuwMF.png)

What i am trying to check is if there is any overlap of time (not date) of person in any other booking. As person can not be at 2 places at same time. Its fine if booking start time is same as end time of another booking.

I am using query below but it returns me nothing but the screenshot i have attached there is overlap of time. Booking end time of booking_id 1 falls between start and end time of booking_id 2.

```
select * from booking_person y 
where exists (
    select 1 from booking_person y2 
    where y.booking_id <> y2.booking_id 
    and y.person_id = y2.person_id 
    and FROM_UNIXTIME(y.date_time) BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(y2.date_time) and FROM_UNIXTIME(y2.date_time_end)
    and FROM_UNIXTIME(y.date_time_end) BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(y2.date_time) and FROM_UNIXTIME(y2.date_time_end)     
)
order by person_id
```

Comment: The logic to check for overlapping periods is: `1st.begin <= 2nd.end and 1st.end >= 2nd.begin`. Depending on your logic you might have to replace `<=/>=` with `</>`. Additionally there's no need for applying `FROM_UNIXTIME` for comparison.#

Comment: In order to achieve what you are looking for, you need to `INNER JOIN` the table with itself and set the `ON` conditions such that the start of a period falls between the start and end of another period OR the end of a period falls between the start and end of another period.

Answer (score 0):

The logic for an overlap of two time periods is:

- the first starts before the second ends
- the first ends after the second starts

You can translate this into SQL as:

```
select bp.*
from booking_person bp 
where exists (select 1
              from booking_person bp2 
              where bp2.person_id = bp.person_id and
                    bp2.booking_id <> bp.booking_id and
                    bp2.date_time < bp.date_time_end and
                    bp2.date_time_end > bp.date_time
             )
order by bp.person_id;
```

Note that this uses strict inequalities.  I am not sure if the end points count for overlapping.  This version does not consider overlaps on end points to be overlaps.